# Why does DependencyObject.MemberwiseClone act this way?

Tags: c#

Why does calling ShallowCopy below fail the Debug.Assert? I expect that the two properties are referencing different collections.

```
public class MyClass : DependencyObject
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Items",
        typeof(ObservableCollection<int>),
        typeof(MyClass),
        new PropertyMetadata(default(ObservableCollection<int>)));

    public ObservableCollection<int> Items
    {
        get { return (ObservableCollection<int>)GetValue(ItemsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ItemsProperty, value); }
    }

    public MyClass ShallowCopy()
    {
        Items = new ObservableCollection<int>();

        var copy = (MyClass)this.MemberwiseClone();
        copy.Items = new ObservableCollection<int>();

       Debug.Assert(!ReferenceEquals(copy.Items,Items), "WHY???");
       return copy;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not that surprising if you think about it. MemberwiseClone is inherited from object and it does a shallow copy. This includes a shallow copy of the reference to the storage the property system is using for the DependencyProperty Items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot clone arbitrary objects. A given object must support being cloned. Calling `Object.MemberwiseClone` on anything is unsafe by default unless you can show it's safe.

For example, what would cloning a `FileStream` or a `Button` do in your mind? It does not make sense.

It's like when you use private reflection to mess with some object's internal state. You get undefined behavior. Really, anything can happen.

If you are curious why you are getting this exact behavior you need to decompile `DependencyObject.Items.set` to see why are corrupted `DependencyObject` might misbehave in such a way. My guess: Both the old and the new object are sharing some state due to all fields just being copied over. That's why setting `Items` on one object also sets it on the other. It's really the same variable underneath.

`Object.MemberwiseClone` is a design mistake in the .NET Framework because it is not possible to protect that method adequately. It's mere existence is unsafe by default as you found out.

Comment: I shall avoid the method.